# javascript refresh popup from another popup

Tags: javascript

```
Window A opens window B
Window A opens window C

On Window C (after user action) I need Window B refreshed.
```

some more explanation:
yes. Window A is the main calendar. window B is opened manually and is smaller and shows stats about the calendar (window A)

When user clicks on a calendar event in window A then Window C opens.  And when the user changes info on Window C then Window B (stats) needs to update.

Comment: Do you really need to open multiple windows, potentially confusing your user? Can you use tabs, modal windows or some other user-friendly method?

Comment: yes. Window A is the main calendar.  window B is smaller and shows stats about window A.  Window C is the ui that shows details about the calendar event just clicked. And When user changes info on window c then window b (stats) must change.

Comment: I answered then deleted it - did you change the question to say "I need window B refreshed" (and not A) or am I going crazy?

Comment: hi jamietre - I think you are going crazy. I didn't change that. only added further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I have to warn you that what you are trying to achieve is not a good practice.

Many browsers are opening new tabs instead of new windows, which can influence the availability of the `window.opener` . Although this depends heavily on the browser settings.

So first of all you should test to see that your code is really opening new windows, not new tabs.

Now, in a.html you should have this:

```
var windowB=window.open("b.html");
var windowC=window.open("c.html");
```

In c.html you should have this:

```
function openNewPage() {
  window.opener.windowB.location.reload(true);
}
```

and call the openNewPage() function on user interaction.

Comment: thanks. so I didn't know the window.opener will be null if the browser opens it as tabs. that really blows. is there any way around this? if not, my only solution is to just keep updating window b on a timer which I didn't want to do.

Comment: so here's the super simple solution.

in window A

window.open("blah.aspx", "windowB");

and then just do it again in window c

window.open("blah.aspx", "windowB");

Answer (score 0):

You need to set references to each other the child windows to each other. Here's a simple demo.

```
var b= window.open('');
var c= window.open('');

b.test=function() {
    alert('Function in window B');  
};

c.test=function() {
    b.test();
    return false;
};
$(b.document).find('body').append('<div>Window B. <a href="#" onclick="return test();">Click here</a></div>');
$(c.document).find('body').append('<div>Window C. <a href="#" onclick="return test();">Click here</a></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ZCX3/25/

Comment: i was only using jquery to set up the example and populate the windows that were created. there is no jquery other than that.

Comment: in your example I don't see how window c could reload window b

Comment: This example just shows how you can call a function in one window from within another. I don't know exactly what you want to do in Window B, but just change the code in `b.test` to do whatever you want. Here's a revision. The first window opens this question. The 2nd is a link. Click something in the 1st window to go to another page, then click the link in the 2nd window and it will reload the same url it started with: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZCX3/37/